# Displaying video in QGIS Print Designer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, video

I would like to know if it is possible to view a video in the QGIS Print Designer

I have tried to do it using the Html video tag, but not possible. I wonder if it is possible to build a video player into Print Designer to play videos.